# Bootstrap menu collapse por cima do texto

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou criando um site que, quando acessado pelo celular, seu menu horizontal é comprimido (collapse), conforme mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem 1]

No entanto, depois que clico no símbolo do menu, as opções aparecem por cima do texto da página e, por isso, não é possível clicar neles. Abaixo coloquei uma imagem do que acontece:

[image: Imagem2]
O que eu gostaria que acontecesse é que a listra em verde expandisse, apresentando as opções do menu e "empurrasse" o texto da página inicial para baixo.

Estou usando a versão 4.3.1 do Bootstrap e as minhas páginas são compostas de três seções, cada uma com seu arquivo correspondente, um exclusivo para o cabeçalho (header.php), outra para o conteúdo (home.php) e a última para o rodapé (footer.php). Todos estes arquivos estão amarrados em um índex.php.

Abaixo, coloco o código de cada seção.

index.php

```
    <?php 

include 'db.php';

include 'header.php';

if(isset($_GET['pagina'])){
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
}
else{
    $pagina = 'home';
}

if($pagina == 'pesquisar'){
    include 'pesquisar.php';
}

if($pagina == 'inicio'){
    include 'views/home.php';
}

include 'footer.php';
```

header.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="?pagina=inicio">
                            <img src="img/logo2.png" width="200" height="40"
                                 class="d-inline-block align-top">
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#nav1" aria-controls="nav1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Navegação Toggle">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav1">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="?pagina=inicio" class="nav-link">Início</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="?pagina=quem_somos" class="nav-link">Saiba mais!</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="?pagina=placar" class="nav-link">Placar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="?pagina=contato" class="nav-link">Contato</a>
                                </li>

                                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario'] || $nivel == membro) {} else { ?>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="?pagina=pesquisar" class="nav-link"> Pesquisar</a>
                                    </li> 
                                <?php } ?>

                                 <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) {} else { ?>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="?pagina=anunciar" class="nav-link"> Anunciar</a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) {} else { ?>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="?pagina=perfil" class="nav-link"> Perfil</a>
                                    </li>  <?php } ?>
                                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario'] || $nivel == membro) {} else { ?>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="?pagina=efigs" class="nav-link"> E-Figs</a>
                                    </li> <?php } ?>
                                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) {} else { ?>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="logout.php" class="nav-link"> Sair</a>
                                    </li> <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

home.php

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 order-1">
                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) { ?>    
                    <br>
                    <h1 align="left">Bemindo!</h1>
                    <p align="left">Aquirro!</p>
                    <p align="left">Noselas!</p>
                    <br>
                    <img src="img/intro.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" 
                         width="500" 
                         height="300"
                         class="img-fluid">

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <br>
                    <h2>Cfig.</h2>
                    <br>
                    <p>Leas.</p>
                    <br>
                    <p>Foara!</p>
                    <br>
                    <p>so:</p>
                    <br>

                    <div class="row" align="center">
                        <figure>
                        <img src="img/comum.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" 
                         width="100" 
                         height="160">  
                        <figcaption align="center">Comum</figcaption></figure> &nbsp;

                        <figure>
                        <img src="img/incomum.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" 
                         width="100" 
                         height="160">
                        <figcaption align="center">Incomum</figcaption></figure> &nbsp;

                        <figure>
                        <img src="img/intermed.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" 
                         width="100" 
                         height="160"> 
                        <figcaption align="center">Intermediário</figcaption></figure> &nbsp;

                        <figure>
                        <img src="img/rara.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" 
                         width="100" 
                         height="160">  
                        <figcaption align="center">Raro</figcaption></figure> 
                    </div>

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 order-2">
                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) { ?>

                    <br><br>
                    <h2 align="center">Faça seu Login:</h2>
                    <br>
                    <form method="POST" action="login.php" align="center">
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" id="login">
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    <p style="font-size:12px" align="center">Não possui cadastro? Clique <a href="?pagina=cadastro">aqui</a>!</p>

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <br><br>
                    <h2>Inserir:</h2>
                    <br><br>
                    <form method="post" action="processa_dados.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="imagem">

                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                        <br>
                    </form>
                                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

footer.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.bg{
            background-color: darkseagreen;
            height: 60px;
        }
        p.fonte{
            font-size:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
</body>
<footer>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row bg">
            <div class="col" align="center">
                <p class="fonte">Apoio:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col" align="center">
                <p class="fonte">Este site está em contínua melhoria</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col" align="center">
                <p class="fonte">Contato:</p>
                <br>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Testando aqui seu código já faz isso ([veja aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/mg0bjpyc/)). Onde você está colocando texto que vem abaixo da nav?

Comment: O que seria essa classe `bg`?

Comment: Cara coloque o código de forma que pelo menos a gente possa simular o seu problema, da forma que está ai não tem como te responder direito...

Comment: Olá, obrigado por todas as sugestões! Coloquei mais informações na pergunta... Basicamente, a pagina esta estruturada em uma página índex (índex.php), dividida em cabeçalho, corpo e rodapé. O texto que está abaixo da nav encontra-se no arquivo home.php, enquanto o cabeçalho esta em header.php. Sam, sobre a classe bg, criei ela para deixar o fundo do cabeçalho verde. Agradeço qualquer sugestão para enriquecer a pergunta... ainda sou novo no stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc limitou o tamanho da `nav` com um `height de 60px`. Dessa forma quando o conteúdo expande ele vai para fora da `nav`. Tipo que a `nav` não cresce junto pq está limitada em 60px, ai não tem como empurrar o restante do conteúdo para baixo já que ela sempre vai ter 60px.

Uma dica que te dou caso queira aumentar a altura da nav é colocar uma margem na logo, por exemplo usando a classe nativa de margem do Bootstrap para dar um espaço acima e abaixo, `my-5` na img.logo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    div.bg {
        background-color: darkseagreen;
        /* height: 60px; */
    }

    p.fonte {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row bg">
            <div class="col-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="?pagina=inicio">
                        <img src="img/logo2.png" width="200" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top  my-5">
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav1" aria-controls="nav1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Navegação Toggle">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav1">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=inicio" class="nav-link">Início</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=quem_somos" class="nav-link">Saiba mais!</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=placar" class="nav-link">Placar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=contato" class="nav-link">Contato</a>
                            </li>

                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario'] || $nivel == membro) {} else { ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=pesquisar" class="nav-link"> Pesquisar</a>
                            </li>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) {} else { ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=anunciar" class="nav-link"> Anunciar</a>
                            </li>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) {} else { ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=perfil" class="nav-link"> Perfil</a>
                            </li> <?php } ?>
                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario'] || $nivel == membro) {} else { ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="?pagina=efigs" class="nav-link"> E-Figs</a>
                            </li> <?php } ?>
                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) {} else { ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="logout.php" class="nav-link"> Sair</a>
                            </li> <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 order-1">
                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) { ?>
                <br>
                <h1 align="left">Bemindo!</h1>
                <p align="left">Aquirro!</p>
                <p align="left">Noselas!</p>
                <br>
                <img src="img/intro.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" width="500" height="300" class="img-fluid">

                <?php } else { ?>

                <br>
                <h2>Cfig.</h2>
                <br>
                <p>Leas.</p>
                <br>
                <p>Foara!</p>
                <br>
                <p>so:</p>
                <br>

                <div class="row" align="center">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/comum.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" width="100" height="160">
                        <figcaption align="center">Comum</figcaption>
                    </figure> &nbsp;

                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/incomum.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" width="100" height="160">
                        <figcaption align="center">Incomum</figcaption>
                    </figure> &nbsp;

                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/intermed.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" width="100" height="160">
                        <figcaption align="center">Intermediário</figcaption>
                    </figure> &nbsp;

                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/rara.png" title="Como Funciona?" alt="Como Funciona?" width="100" height="160">
                        <figcaption align="center">Raro</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 order-2">
                <?php if (!$_SESSION['usuario']) { ?>

                <br><br>
                <h2 align="center">Faça seu Login:</h2>
                <br>
                <form method="POST" action="login.php" align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" id="login">
                </form>
                <br>
                <p style="font-size:12px" align="center">Não possui cadastro? Clique <a href="?pagina=cadastro">aqui</a>!</p>

                <?php } else { ?>

                <br><br>
                <h2>Inserir:</h2>
                <br><br>
                <form method="post" action="processa_dados.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="imagem">

                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                    <br>
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <footer>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg">
                <div class="col" align="center">
                    <p class="fonte">Apoio:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col" align="center">
                    <p class="fonte">Este site está em contínua melhoria</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col" align="center">
                    <p class="fonte">Contato:</p>
                    <br>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hugo, fiz a alteração e funcionou exatamente da forma que eu queria! Muito obrigado pela sua resposta!

Comment: @PedroSchimmelpfeng se te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar a pergunta como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da minha resposta. Hhaha Valeu a força jovem!